# Add Confirmation Popup to Flask Form

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I'm wondering how you would add a confirmation popup to a form submit in Flask. I come from a javascript background, so I would imagine you would have an onClick() event that opens a modal asking for confirmation but I can't seem to figure out how to do that with flask.

```
<form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    {{ form.hidden_tag() if form.hidden_tag }}
    {% for f in form if f.type != 'CSRFTokenField' %}

        {% if f.type == 'BooleanField' %}
            {{ f.label }} {{ f(checked=False) }}
        {% else %}
            {{ f(class_='form-control ') }}
        {% endif %}

        {% if f.errors %}
        <ul>
            {% for e in f.errors %}
            <li>{{ e }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    <br />

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
    <a class="btn btn-link" href="/"><i class="icon-arrow-left icon-white"></i>Back</a>
</form>
```

Basically this form allows the user to delete some records from our db, and I'd like a confirmation popup to happen when they hit submit to say "Hey, are you really sure you want to do this?!".

Thanks

Comment: Having been an avid user of Flask myself, I think that you may be much better off using javascript in this case. You don't really want a page reload between clicking submit and the modal and then yet another for the actual submission.

Comment: How would you add javascript to this template if it's part of a flask admin page though? Could I just add something like onsubmit="return confirm('Do you really want to submit the form?');" to the <buttom>?

Comment: I'd add javascript either in script tags, or even better at the bottom of the page if at all possible. Then in the script, prevent default to avoid actually submitting it and then if they click yes, then call event.target.submit() or something like that - I'm fairly confident that you should be able to submit from the event.

Comment: So the onsubmit can equal handlesubmit which is a function to prevent the default and launch the confirmation popup and if yes, then submit it.